# How to make a custom dropdown movable with div scrolliing?

Tags: html, css

I have created a custom dropdown as shown and is correct as required:

[image: Custom dropdown 1]

But when I am scrolling the page it is getting changed to:

[image: Custom Dropdown 2]

The div is scrolling with the page, but since my custom dropdown's position is absolute, it is not moving along with div, which is wrong.

The Css for the custom dropdown is :

```
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 25%;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: -1%;
    border: 1px solid #62B7DF;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px -3px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    z-index: 1;
```

Any idea how do I made it work?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the HTML for the dropdown, including its parent. The dropdown's position is influenced by its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of your dropdown that scrolls with its target div. The things that make it work are:

1. The dropdown's parent is the target div.
2. The target div has the style `position: relative`.

```js
function showhide () {
  const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  dropdown.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  width: 30%;
  height: 6rem;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-left: -1%;
  border: 1px solid #62B7DF;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px -3px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}

.target {
  position: relative;
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h4>A dropdown that scrolls with target
  <button onclick="showhide();">Show/Hide</button>
  </h4>
  
  <div class="target">
    .target
    <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown hidden">
      .dropdown
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Content in the next div</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks . I did a bit of manipulation in your solution to made it work. Thanks for the idea. Thanks Buddy.

Comment: @NeerajNeeraj You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. Will you accept my answer, please?